# RTP Stream shows gray background then crashes

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, wireshark, h.264, transport-stream

I'm trying to play some RTP stream in python using opencv and an SDP file. I'm getting a gray window with some distorted images at the top(see attached image) and after a few seconds the program would crash and the gray window would close.

[image: output]

I also tried to capture the packets of the stream via wireshark and extract the video information using media info.

Note:The extracted video was playing smoothly.

[image: capture]

Media information using GSpot

[image: another]

The SDP file contains:

```
v=0
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 103
c=IN IP4 239.194.115.71
a=rtpmap:103 H264/90000
```

These are the error codes shown in the terminal:

```
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 2 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] error while decoding MB 2 0, bytestream 353
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] error while decoding MB 58 2, bytestream -11
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c8d85c0] error while decoding MB 13 3, bytestream -9
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] error while decoding MB 2 0, bytestream 353
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] error while decoding MB 58 2, bytestream -11
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] error while decoding MB 13 3, bytestream -9
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 59 2
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] error while decoding MB 59 2, bytestream 217
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 70 1
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] error while decoding MB 70 1, bytestream 337
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] error while decoding MB 71 2, bytestream -17
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] error while decoding MB 33 2, bytestream -11
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] error while decoding MB 2 0, bytestream 371
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 11, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 118 1
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] error while decoding MB 118 1, bytestream 379
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 70 1
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] error while decoding MB 70 1, bytestream 377
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3cf7c940] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e540] Invalid NAL unit 10, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0000029d3393e9c0] error while decoding MB 4 0, bytestream 291
[h264 @ 0000029d3c952300] Invalid NAL unit 12, skipping.
[h264 @ 00
Process finished with exit code -1
```

Python code:

```
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.sdp')

while (1):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

wireshark dump:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zppjXVgEcL8Ws-xP3e1J7NJF1UGdPzMA

Am I using a wrong codec code or clock-rate inside the SDP file for it to display the stream properly?

Comment: Tried on VLC, it shows a black screen with little bit image at the upper left side. 
here is the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/bdZaZPf.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the video stream is starting with SPS,PPS. you can check this in the wireshark.( share the wireshark dump, if you can)

Start your python script first and then start streaming from the live camera.

This will insure you are not missing out any initial frames from the ip camera.

there is no problem with sampling frequency of rtp.

Comment: you can see the wireshark dump here:  https://i.imgur.com/hMyRs3N.png

Comment: Can you share the pcap file , not the snap shot ?

Comment: here it is: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zppjXVgEcL8Ws-xP3e1J7NJF1UGdPzMA

Answer (score 0):

there is some kind of problem with ffmpeg decoding the frames, I used VLC's python bindings instead

[image]